# Would complimenting someone's physical appearance be considered a problem since it causes the person to become overly conscious of themselves?

Tags: lashon-hara-slander, chesed-kindness, beauty

Let me clarify that I don't mean compliments in an inappropriate sense such has calling someone attractive or specifying a rude area of one's body.

I'm speaking to examples like:

- You have a great beard!
- I really love your hat!
- You look fantastic! (after weight loss)

While compliments like this might seem harmless at face value, would it also be problematic from the mindset it may cause someone to become more aware or obsessed with their physical appearance?

Comment: What exactly is your halachic question? Are you asking whether it's appropriate to avoid causing another distress, or are you looking for a specific prohibition against complimenting?

Comment: This is coming from a place regarding how the Rabbis would define a compliment in relationship to obsessing over oneself and in relation to how we should choose words carefully when speaking to others.

We're taught not to be overly obsessive about one's looks. We're also taught to speak consciously in choosing our words to not say the wrong thing. I was curious if a compliment or being overly complimentary might somehow edge along a violation if it results in a Jew becoming overly conscious about their appearance or results in a Jew comparing oneself to others?

Comment: Giving people a positive self-image is a mitzvah.

Comment: This is the famous sugya of לפני עור במידות. ֱIf you Google this expression, I'm sure you are going to find relevant מראי מקומות.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this Dvar Torah [I wrote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oc6PJ35BEXmDwD337XUNv42RymaNGMiO/view?usp=drive_link), with ideas and sources there, I would conclude that the problem you mention is real, and there is a solution.

The root cause that this would make them feel self conscious is because it carries the message that the superficial parts of them are all people care about. This implies that they themself are irrelevant, and that makes them feel alone.

The solution is to give the compliment in a way that does not imply that. This might not need to be overt: if the person you are talking to knows that *they themself* are unconditionally important to you, then it would be rare that they would feel self conscious from a compliment from you. If they don't have that impression, then one will need to find a way to show them that they are what matters, not the "things about them", and thus *because* **they** matter to you, the things about them *thus* matter to you too.

> “You’ve got lots of nice things about you, because you are amazing,
> but it’s not those things that I like about you. I just like you!”.

See the Dvar Torah for more discussion and examples of this, but generally speaking this is an art that each person should develop, and the first step in that is to solidify in their mind that people are someones, not somethings, and develop a sensitivity to the infinite preciousness of people, and the infinite vanity of "things".

I.e. study lots of Torah. Rabbi Manis Friedman also teaches this message a lot, and if one watches many of [his lectures](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnkB28NTo_OxXTYjCUv7m5Q) alongside their learning, one will certainly absorb the point deeply. Hatzlacha!

Comment: I should also add that every father should definitely tell his daughter she is gorgeous!